# JavaScript MD5 differs from Python/Bash md5sum

Tags: javascript, python, md5, md5sum

I have the following snippet

```
    function runUpload( file ) {
        key_name = file.name
        if( file.type === 'image/png'  || 
                file.type === 'image/jpg'  || 
            file.type === 'image/jpeg' ||
                file.type === 'image/gif'  ||
                file.type === 'image/bmp'  ){
            var reader = new FileReader(),
                    image = new Image();
            reader.readAsDataURL( file );
            reader.onload = function( _file ){
                keyhash = md5(atob(_file.target.result.split(',')[1]));
                ZZ('key').el.src = _file.target.result;
                ZZ('key').el.style.display = 'block';
            } 
        } 
    }
```

The reason that the split happens is because if I left it at just:

```
_file.target.result
```

The resulting string would be:

```
data:text/plain;base64,SEVMTE8=
```

It uses https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5/master/js/md5.min.js

The value of keyhash is different from when I do:

```
cat file.png | md5sum
```

Also when doing the python below, it gives me a different value to the JS version but the same as Linux

```
import hashlib

def md5Checksum(filePath):
    with open(filePath, 'rb') as fh:
        m = hashlib.md5()
        while True:
            data = fh.read(8192)
            if not data:
                break
            m.update(data)
        return m.hexdigest()

print('The MD5 checksum of text.txt is', md5Checksum('000000.png'))
```

Am I missing something obvious or should they all return the same value?

JS: `dc839221df178f70c08fa510a3d76a3b`
Python and MD5SUM: `9310dad66d4a73e29a761fb724f2825`

In fact, if I have a file called HELLO.txt and the only content in there is: `HELLO`

base64'ing it in Linux/Python give the same result which is different to when JS does it.

```
SEVMTE8K vs SEVMTE8=
```

I think it may be something to do with new lines, break likes, return carriages etc

JavaScript has it as one continuous stream whereas editing the file in an text editor shows line breaks

Thanks

Comment: `_file.target.result.split(',')[1]`, what is this for?

Comment: The Javascript function brings back data:image/png;base64 (or similar) at the start and then the content of the file, all of which is separated by the comma

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation is that encoding is different. Figure out encoding in JS (ISO-8859-1) to that in python (UTF-8).